# highchartjs do not show time on tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am a bit new to Highcharts.  I would like to display the date only on the tooltip hover. (currently it is showing date and time).  here is the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/c8Ldw23q/1/   you will notice if you hover over the data points the tooltip shows date with time. I would like date only.

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Daily Calories'
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                xAxis: {
                     categories: data.Plots.map(a => new Date(a.Day)),
                    type: 'datetime',
                    //dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                       // day: '%m/%d/%Y'
                   // },
                    labels: {
                        format: '{value:%Y-%b-%e}'
                    },

                },
                yAxis: {
                    // minRange: 2 * Math.abs(@ViewBag.CFAvg - @Model.MyAverage),
                    title: {
                        text: 'Calories'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        color: 'blue',
                        value: data.MyAverage,
                        width: 2,
                        zIndex: 2,
                        label: {
                            text: 'Average Calories (' + data.MyAverage + ')'
                        }
                    }]
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Calories',
                    data: data.Plots.map(a => a.TotalCalories),
                    color: 'rgb(4, 83, 4)',
                    //pointStart: Date.UTC(new Date(data.StartDate).getFullYear(), new Date(data.StartDate).getMonth(), new Date(data.StartDate).getDate()), //start date
                   // pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 // one day
                }],
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose exactly what you want to show on the `tooltip` by editing the `formatter` for the tooltip, to get what you are after you can use the following:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return Highcharts.dateFormat("%Y-%b-%e", this.x) + 
      '<br/><b>' + this.series.name + '</b>: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0 , '', ' ');
  }
}
```

What this does is that it replaces the default formatting for the tooltip. `Dateformat` outputs the `datetime` to your chosen string. `Numberformat` in this example adds space as the thousand-separator and sets the number to have 0 decimals.

If you want to show the `datetime` in a different way, refer to this page to find the needed syntax: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/c8Ldw23q/3/

**API on tooltip.formatter:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Highcharts.dateFormat` to customize how the Date should be displayed. See the [function documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.dateFormat) for more info.

Example:

```
Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y/%m/%d', new Date(a.Day))
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zga4mnrw/

Result:

[image]